# setting content in multiple regions with panels

Tags: blocks, panels, nodes

I am trying to make a website, and I am needing some advices to solve a problem that I have, I will begin saying that I am using drupal 7, with panels and some other stuff, this is an example of the front page that I have thus far:

```
/**********************************************************************************
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                              header                                             *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
***********************************************************************************
*             *                                                       *           *
*             *                                                       *           *
*             *                                                       *           *
*             *                      section                          *           *
*             *                                                       *           *
*             *                                                       *           *
*             *                                                       *           *
*             *                                                       *           *
*             * *******************************************************           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
*             *            section         *          section         *           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
***********************************************************************************
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                              footer                                             *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
**********************************************************************************/
```

in my front page I have a section that I will use to show a message, but I am trying to make everything reusable, besides, I'd like to make everything with a neat structure, I'd like to make something like this:

```
/**********************************************************************************
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                              header                                             *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
***********************************************************************************
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                                    highlighted                                  *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
***********************************************************************************
*             *                            *                          *           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
*             *            section         *          section         *           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
*             *                            *                          *           *
***********************************************************************************
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                              footer                                             *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
*                                                                                 *
**********************************************************************************/
```

I'd like to turn that section into a region called higlighted, that region can be used in other pages, I tried to add a block into that region and then set some content dinamically to highlighted and content region, but it doesn't work like that, I don't know any other way to set content to the highlighted and the content region.

so, is there a possible way to do this??

Comment: I was going to include an image but I could not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For static content, you can choose *New custom content* from the Panels *Add content* screen.  Once you do so, you can check *Make this content reusable* at the bottom of the form that appears.

For dynamic content, the most general and commonly used way is the [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.  Using contextual filters, you can create a block that is dynamically changed based on the page url, taxonomy terms present on the page, or in other various ways.  Moreover, although they are a little trickier to set up, you can use Views to make content panes, which are a special type of "block" specifically for Panels (Panels and Views were both developed originally by Earl Miles).

I can't explain how to do all of this here, but Node One has an excellent series of screencasts on [Learning Views](http://nodeone.se/en/taming-the-beast-learn-views-with-nodeone) and [Learning Page Manager/Panels](http://nodeone.se/node/682).